# PHPStorm and WordPress project errors

Tags: wordpress, syntax-error, phpstorm

I'm using `PHPStorm` while develop `WordPress` plugins (mainly for HTML/CSS/JS).

Each plugin is a separate `PHPStorm` project since I can have several goodies from using this way.

The issue is when working on a plugin, the `WordPress` functions like `_e` are marked as `Warnings` (yellow color) and the information `PHPStorm` gives is that

```
"Undefined function _e"
```

How can I configure `PHPStorm` that it understand the `WordPress` functions and do not shows that errors and autocomplete the functions without to have a big project wrapping the `WordPress` installation?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on what you have setup there ... but you need to reference WordPress somehow (so that PhpStorm knows what those functions are). The simplest way -- **add WordPress code as External Library** -- `Settings | PHP | Include paths`

Comment: @LazyOne: Thanks for your comment. I already tried that and sadly don't worked for me :( Have you another suggestion on how it can be done? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not working with WordPress .. so do not have much ideas what `_e` function is, how it should be used and why it does not work for you. But if you wish... try making WordPress code as part of the project -- `Settings | Directories | Add Content Root` -- it's a bit different to External Libraries (as this time it is part of the actual project files)

Comment: I use NetBeans, but the solution is the same @LazyOne is pointing out.

Comment: @LazyOne: Hey! That worked like a charm! :D Now the errors of undefined functions are gone away. Thanks! Can you post this as an answer to mark it as the right one?

Comment: @brasofilo: Thanks for take time to answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to reference WordPress code in some way. Few possible approaches:

1. Add **as External Library** -- perfect for referencing only: `Settings | PHP | Include paths`
2. Add **as part of the project itself** (careful, as in this case WP code will be used during Search/Refactor/etc operations) -- `Settings | Directories | Add Content Root`
3. Symbolic link somewhere in the project (but #2 is still better for your case)

Comment: Accepted! ;) I will report to JetBrains the issue with the via 1 since is the perfect way to do it. Until the issue is solver I will stick with 2. Thanks again.